# Android : How to access phone via PC?

Tags: android, remote-desktop, rtsp, remote-access, vnc

I want to create a app to access my android device via PC.
I have already seen such apps available, but i want to code my own.

Can any one guide me to create such app?

what do I need to start coding?
what kind of protocols, connection types(wifi, internet, bluetooth), libraries do I require?
Is there any build in API that could help me?

I need to access my phone and use it remotely via my PC and I want to code this myself.

Thanks 
Abhinav Tyagi

Comment: What kind of access you want? I mean, do you wanna transfer data only or able to call, open other application, to handle phone remotely?

Comment: Please guide me in right direction :(

Comment: I think you want to build application like PC suite. If it is so then you have to code a alot and requires different-2 applications to be combined. First think what you want, not just the possible, since EVERYTHING IS POSSIBLE.

Comment: I want functionality similar to remote desktop but here I want remote android device. There are apps available but I want to do it my way. at the moment a simple navigation and open app can help

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to access, first you need to have a communication to that device. So my advice is use the TCP/IP protocol to communicate, i.e. The socket programming is needed on both side PC and device to communicate. Then parse the data according to the strategy you follow to send over network. Make the standard to communicate like have some command with specific argument to perform some specific task and the size, interval, order of the arguments.
So with the help of that structure of communication you can execute the operations on both side. 
For example, to get the contact list of phone on device, First query the device and convert the contacts list in a object list format and send over network. Then using the reverse coding of the data packet into objects, display the contacts list on the remote device.

Answer (score 0):

RUNNING APP ON DEVICE THROUGH REMOTE
On the basis of other answer follow the strategy and on device first get the list of packages available and send over network. When the remote pc/device wants to run that app, just send the complete package name with some extra info you want. Now on the device side parse that string and extra arguments and run the activity with that intent.

Comment: How can I see phone screen on PC through this?
Any code example you have?